# How to split pie chart in matplotlib while maintaining values generated using autopct

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to split a pie chart in to 2 from the same set of values. I have a list containing covid data, 98.4% of which is from china, the rest, from 20 different countries. It generates a pie chart where you can't even see the individual values.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
country_values = []
country_labels = []

for country in country_records:
   country_values.append(country.cases)
   country_labels.append(country.name)

plt.pie(country_values, autopct='%.1f%%')
plt.legend(labels = country_labels, loc = "upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 1.15))
plt.show()
```

can I split the pie chart in to 2 pie charts, creating one solid pie chart and one with the remaining countries, while maintaining the values generated by autopct?

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the following code to your own use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import numpy as np

# make figure and assign axis objects
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 5.0625))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

# large pie chart parameters
ratios = [.20, .50, .30]
labels = ['Other', 'China', 'India']
explode = [0.1, 0, 0]
# rotate so that first wedge is split by the x-axis
angle = -180 * ratios[0]
ax1.pie(ratios, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=angle,
        labels=labels, explode=explode)

# small pie chart parameters
ratios = [.10, .20, .30, .40]
labels = ['Portugal', 'Spain', 'Germany', 'France']
width = .2
angle = -90 * ratios[0]
ax2.pie(ratios, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=angle,
        labels=labels, radius=0.5, textprops={'size': 'smaller'})

ax1.set_title('Countries')
ax2.set_title('Europe')

# use ConnectionPatch to draw lines between the two plots
# get the wedge data
theta1, theta2 = ax1.patches[0].theta1, ax1.patches[0].theta2
center, r = ax1.patches[0].center, ax1.patches[0].r

# draw top connecting line
x = r * np.cos(np.pi / 180 * theta2) + center[0]
y = np.sin(np.pi / 180 * theta2) + center[1]
con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(- width / 2, .5), xyB=(x, y),
                      coordsA="data", coordsB="data", axesA=ax2, axesB=ax1)
con.set_color([0, 0, 0])
con.set_linewidth(2)
ax2.add_artist(con)

# draw bottom connecting line
x = r * np.cos(np.pi / 180 * theta1) + center[0]
y = np.sin(np.pi / 180 * theta1) + center[1]
con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(- width / 2, -.5), xyB=(x, y), coordsA="data",
                      coordsB="data", axesA=ax2, axesB=ax1)
con.set_color([0, 0, 0])
ax2.add_artist(con)
con.set_linewidth(2)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]